# Displaying text after some time in Angular 2

Tags: angular

I would like to check if a div is opened for 5 seconds, and then show an element in my parent div. So I got like this:

```
<div (click)="opened = !opened"><p>show me after 5 seconds</p></div>
<div *ngIf="opened"></div>
```

On click i'll open another div, and I need to display an element in the first div after 5 seconds of 2nd div being opened. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Use debounce , looks better :P

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

In your HTML template:

```
<div (click)="onClick()"><p *ngIf="pOpened">show me after 5 seconds</p></div>
<div *ngIf="opened"></div>
```

In your component:

```
public onClick = () => {
    this.opened = !this.opened;
    setTimeout(() => {this.pOpened = this.opened}, 5000);
}
```

Comment: Same thought, time difference

Answer (score 1):

Change html template like this

```
<div (click)="onClick($event)"><p *ngIf="showMe">show me after 5 seconds</p></div>
<div *ngIf="opened"></div>
```

Now in class define `onClick` method, `opened` and `showMe`

```
opened: boolean = false;
showMe: boolean = false;

onClick(event) {
   if(!this.opened) {
       this.opened = true;
       setTimeout(() => {
            this.showMe = true;
       }, 5000)
   }
}
```

If you want to **toggle** the div

```
onClick(event) {
   if(!this.opened) {
       this.opened = !this.opened;
       if(!this.showMe){
           setTimeout(() => {
               this.showMe = !this.showMe;
           }, 5000);
       } else {
           this.showMe = !this.showMe;
       }
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

use `setTimeOut` function.

**// html**

```
<div (click)="open(opened)"><p>show me after 5 seconds</p></div>
```

**// component**

```
open(opened: boolean){
     setTimeout(function(){
          this.opened = !opened;
        },3000);
    }
```